# How can I add an image logo to a SpreadSheet using Document.OpenXML in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm facing problem while exporting image in excel multiple sheet .
Below code is  written

```vb
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
Imports DocumentFormat
Imports System.IO
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation
Private Sub ds2ExcelOpenXML(ByVal ds As DataSet)
Try
   Dim strFileName As String = "C:\\Users\\psupriya\\Documents\\TestExportToXL.xlsx"
  

   Dim sLogoPath As String = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Application.StartupPath, "Logo","venturalogo.png")
   Using workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(strFileName,  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, True)


   Dim workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart()
   workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook()
   workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets()
               
    For Each table As System.Data.DataTable In ds.Tables                   
    Dim sheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
    Dim sheetData = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData()
    sheetPart.Worksheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData)
    Dim sheets As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets)()
    Dim relationshipId As String = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart)
    Dim sheetId As UInteger = 1
    If sheets.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet)().Count() > 0 Then
    sheetId = CUInt(sheets.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet)().[Select](Function(s) s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1)
    End If
    Dim sheetXL As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() With {
     .Id = relationshipId,
     .SheetId = sheetId,
     .Name = table.TableName
     }
                
   sheets.Append(sheetXL)
   For i = 0 To 4
   Dim newRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
   Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
   sheetData.AppendChild(newRow)
   Next
   Dim headerRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
   Dim columns As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
   For Each column As System.Data.DataColumn In table.Columns
       columns.Add(column.ColumnName)
       Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
       cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
       cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName)
       headerRow.AppendChild(cell)
   Next
   sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow)
   For Each dsrow As System.Data.DataRow In table.Rows
       Dim newRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
       For Each col As String In columns
           Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
           cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
           cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow(col).ToString())
           newRow.AppendChild(cell)
    Next
    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow)
    Next
    ' --------------------------Add Image                 
    Dim drawingsPart = sheetPart.DrawingsPart
    If sheetPart.DrawingsPart IsNot Nothing Then
        drawingsPart = sheetPart.DrawingsPart
    Else
        drawingsPart = sheetPart.AddNewPart(Of DrawingsPart)()
        sheetPart.Worksheet.Append(New Drawing() With {.Id = sheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart)})
    End If
   
    Dim imageId As String = "image" & sheetPart.DrawingsPart.ImageParts.Count() + 1
    'Dim imgp As ImagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(Of ImagePart)(ImagePartType.Png, imageId)
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim data() As Byte = wc.DownloadData(sLogoPath)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
    Dim imgp As ImagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png, imageId)
    imgp.FeedData(ms) 
    Dim imageNumber As Integer = sheetData.Descendants(Of Pictures.Picture)().Count() + 1
    Dim twoCellAnchor As TwoCellAnchor = New TwoCellAnchor(
    New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(New ColumnId("0"), New ColumnOffset("0"),         New RowId("0"), New RowOffset("0")),
                        New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(New ColumnId("10"), New   ColumnOffset("0"), New RowId("4"), New RowOffset("4"))
        )
    
   Dim extents As New Extents()
   extents.Cx = 4500
   extents.Cy = 4500
  
   Dim picture As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Picture()
   picture.NonVisualPictureProperties = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NonVisualPictureProperties(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NonVisualDrawingProperties() With {
       .Id = 1,
       .Name = "venturalogo.png",
       .Description = "Logo"
   }, New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(), New ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties())
   picture.BlipFill = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.BlipFill(New Blip() With {
       .Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imgp),
       .CompressionState = BlipCompressionValues.Print
   }, New Stretch(New FillRectangle()), New SourceRectangle())
   picture.ShapeProperties = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeProperties(New Transform2D(New Offset() With {
       .X = 0,
       .Y = 0
   }, extents), New PresetGeometry(New NoFill()))
  
   Dim worksheetDrawing As WorksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing
   If worksheetDrawing Is Nothing Then
       worksheetDrawing = New WorksheetDrawing()
   End If
   worksheetDrawing.Append(twoCellAnchor)
   worksheetDrawing.Append(picture)
                    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = worksheetDrawing                 
   Next
   End Using           
  Catch ex As Exception           
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)            
 End Try
End Sub

---
```

I am expecting to add Image as logo in SpreadSheet in first column. I have written above code. Code is running fine but while Opening a file image has not been added.

[Expected Output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mta1J.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mta1J.png)

[Getting this wrong Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WYSk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WYSk.png)

Comment: Create an Excel spreadsheet that is representative of the one you are trying to programatically create. Then use [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to see the structure of the Excel spreadsheet. Alternatively, you can change the extension from .xlsx to .zip and then unzip the file.